# Truncating text with jQuery but keep the HTML formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, dom

I repeat here [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610364/how-to-truncate-text-with-jquery-but-keep-the-html-formatting/30611691#30611691).

I first posted an answer with not finalized code, as a simple description of the solution I could think, without any test. But later I remained interested, so I worked to make it (hopefully) perfectly functional.

To precisely define what it is meant to do, let me cite my previous answer:

> This is a classic dilemma for any CMS or blog, where the teaser should present the begin of an article: often the solution is either stripping text from its tags and cut at a precise count OR keep tags but cut approximately because the tags are counted too...

So here the intent is to take an HTML element with any number of children, and any nesting level and return:

- the "same" element (i.e. keeping its tag and attributes)
- where resulting text content (i.e. visible as characters in the resulting page) is limited to a given count
- where resulting text is built from successive text nodes in their natural order
- where encountered tags are keeped intact and at their natural place

Here is my actual solution:

```
function cutKeepingTags(elem, reqCount) {
  var grabText = '',
      missCount = reqCount;
  $(elem).contents().each(function() {
    switch (this.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // Get node text, limited to missCount.
        grabText += this.data.substr(0,missCount);
        missCount -= Math.min(this.data.length, missCount);
        break;
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        // Explore current child:
        var childPart = cutKeepingTags(this, missCount);
        grabText += childPart.text;
        missCount -= childPart.count;
        break;
    }
    if (missCount == 0) {
      // We got text enough, stop looping.
      return false;
    }
  });
  return {
    text:
      // Wrap text using current elem tag.
      elem.outerHTML.match(/^<[^>]+>/m)[0]
      + grabText
      + '</' + elem.localName + '>',
    count: reqCount - missCount
  };
}
```

And here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/7mbxf5hq/). (I kept the HTML example posted by the previous question OP)

Comment: Beware that + '</' + elem.localName + '>' causes <br>-tags to be doubled. I've replaced it with + (elem.localName != 'br' ? '</' + elem.localName + '>' : '').

Comment: @user2806026 Yes! In addition you make me realize that some other tags are same, like `<hr>` or `<img>`. Thanks for pointing this missed case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I would just like to say that this is a really good and useful function. From a Code Review standpoint, there are almost no errors in it that I know of. Here are a few things I found from examining it:

**Keep spacing uniform**
Line 8 doesn't have a space between parameters, where your other function calls do. This is most likely due to quick typing and not any major issue other than a cleanliness nitpick.

**An invalid input for if**
Lines 19-21 where you have an if like so:

```
if (missCount == 0) {
  // We got text enough, stop looping.
  return false;
}
```

You should never use `==` over `===` due to it being possible that something like `"0"` would match the same as `0`. This is because the double equals signs finds if it matches an exact value, where triple equals signs tests for exact value and type. So your final code should look like this for the if statement:

```
if (missCount === 0) {
  // We got text enough, stop looping.
  return false;
}
```

**Optional - JSHint**
If you use JSHint in JSFiddle, then you'll run into errors when trying to run this:

```
elem.outerHTML.match(/^<[^>]+>/m)[0]
  + grabText
  + '</' + elem.localName + '>',
```

If you're worried about that then you just have to write it all on one line. But for being short and concise, that might not be what you want.

Comment: Hey, this is unexpected: funnyly, from a stackOverflow question, I inadvertently put this answer in codeReview! I obviously agree with your first remark. But not for `if (missCount == 0)`: I use to write a full test "===" _only when really needed_. Not the case here: `missCount` comes from `reqCount` then is only submitted to computations. So you made me realize that I rather should have controlled reqCount when entering function. Regarding JSHint diagnoses, I don't understand: I use to break expressions for readability, and don't see anything wrong here. Anyway, thanks for reviewing.

Comment: With the `if (missCount == 0)` part, there is only a very rare case where you would want to use `==` over `===`. Thus, it is best practice to use `===` all the time, and use the opposite if it's ever needed. It's a similar scenario to using single-quotes or double-quotes for strings. This lets you avoid a lot of coding errors when it may give you an unexpected result. Makes for much easier debugging. For the JSHint part, as I said, there is nothing wrong with your code. I was just saying that if you use JSHint available in JSFiddle, it'll give you an error unless you put it on a single line.

Comment: Also, if this answer helped you with cleaning up your code, please hit the check mark below the votes for this answer. That way people know it's resolved.

Comment: As explained above I'd not realized I was in codeReview, so I didn't even think to vote. But I do it now because yes, this answer helped me with cleaning up my code... in an unexpected way. I used JSHint to see the diagnoses you cited, then I tried it with my current app, just by curiosity. And it made me discover that, in a huge sequence of variables declarations after a unique `var`, I'd inadvertently closed a line by ";" instead of ",": so all following variables were declared in the global space. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was of service. :-)

Comment: This is in a different comment because in fact it should rather be in meta section... I don't at all agree with some of the "best practices". Especially the one about choosing between "==" and "===". My point of view is that we should be really careful about what we write, and so I prefer make the effort to be conscious of the implied consequences, rather than take the habit of some facilities. Note that, in this case, always write "===" makes the system to work more (must also control the variable type) in any case,while it may be often useless.

Comment: I see. I just want to point out that the "===" is exactly the same as "==" in C-type languages. C-type languages always check for type too. Why JS went another way with it? I don't know. The point is that using "===" over "==" will make your programs follow the same language standards as almost any other high-level programming language. If you would rather be conscious of that even over hard debugging, then that's fine. I just wanted to point out that "==" not checking type is non-standard in most programming languages, and using "===" is what it should be.

Comment: _Why JS went another way with it?_ Because at the opposite of C, JS is a weakly typed language, so the difference between "==" and "===" is by design. The same applies to PHP. In those languages, it is IMO a great advantage to, at the same time, be more free and be more responsible. Case of taste...